# How do I call a function inside of another function from java script file in html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call the function that is in another function in my HTML file
here is my HTML code:

```
    <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="UnTiled" id="raster" onclick="if(this.checked){myFunction()}">Raster Layer
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js" ></script>
```

and here is my javascript code(main.js):

```
function init(){
function myFunction() {
    alert('hi')
}
}
```

and error is :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
```

Comment: You should use closure [js closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: I think Beller's comment is the answer. I hope he/she will post it as an answer as well.

Comment: yes, I hope too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution snippet

```js
function init(){
  function myFunction() {
    alert('hi');
}
return myFunction();
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="UnTiled" id="raster" onclick="init()">
```

Comment: I found one problem. when open page and before selected radio button, alert is showing

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="UnTiled" id="raster" onclick="myFunction()">Raster Layer
<script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  alert('hi')
}
```

This is my solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

To add some context to the other answer, you are not able to run conditional statements using onClick, only functions.